# Characterization of primes of the form $n^n+1$ by using number-theoretic functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, arithmetic-functions, integer-sequences

It is known that there is a unsolved problem related to primes of the form $n^n+1$ as is explained in page 160 of [1] (see also page 156, and the OEIS page related to this integer sequence [A121270](https://oeis.org/A121270)). In this post I ask about if we can to get a characterization for this sequence of primes in terms of (some) number-theoretic functions.

> **Question.** I would like to get a characterization of these primes $n^n+1$ in terms of number-theoretic functions (see my attempts) It is required that your characterization is  a $\iff$ statement.

My attempt was the following deductions (while which I require is a $\iff$ statement: a characterization in terms of particular values of common arithmetic functions in number theory).

**Claim 1.** *If* $n^n+1$ *is a prime number, then* $$\varphi(\varphi(n^n+1))=\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}(\psi(n^n+1)-2)\tag{1}$$ *holds, where* $\varphi(k)$ *denotes the Euler's Totient Function and $\psi(k)$ denotes the Dedekind Psi Function.*

**Claim 2.** *If* $n^n+1$ *is prime, then the equations*
$$\varphi(\varphi(A))^B=(A-1)^{B-1}\cdot\varphi(B)^B$$
*and* $$\psi(A-1)^B=\psi(B)^B\cdot(A-1)^{B-1}$$
*holds for some choice of integers* $A,B\geq 1$ (take $B=n=\sqrt[B]{A-1}$).

**Computation evidence for Claim 2.** I've tested with a GP program (Sage Cell Server) that the only integers that satisfy both equations are $A=2,5$ and $257$ when the variables run over the integers $2\leq A\leq 10^3$ and $1\leq B\leq 10^3$

### References:

[1] Michael Křižek, Florian Luca and Lawrence Somer, *17 Lectures on Fermat Numbers*, CMS Books in Mathematics, Canadian Mathematical Society, Springer-Verlag (2001).

Comment: If you attempt is improve my propositions, or well use the Dedekind function, I refer that Wikipedia has an article for this function with title *Dedekind psi function*. Just to clarify it you can to use divisors functions, the Euler's totient function, ..., and other number-theoretic functions in your answer.

Comment: How about $n^n+1$ is prime if and only if $\phi(n^n+1)=n^n$?

Comment: This characterization is rather pointless since the next possible prime of this form after $2,5,257$  is $F_{70}$ , the $70$ th Fermat-number. In the (extremely unlikely) case that this (or another further candidate) is prime , we won't be able to prove it within a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Many thanks @GerryMyerson I didn't think in it. And thanks to Peter also. Thanks also for the person who edited the post.

Comment: I would like to refer the nice Master's thesis *On the twin prime conjecture* by Tomasz Buchert (Poznán 2011) that provides several characterization in terms of multiplicative functions for twin primes.

Comment: I've found a bunch of formulas (conjectures as candidates for characterizations) but I need to test these with Pari/GP or Sage, for some segment of integers.

Comment: If $n$ is a power of $2$ then  $n^n+1$ is a Fermat number of the form $F(b+2^b).$ No Fermat primes larger than $F(4)$ are known. I don't think there are any known $general$ results about whether $F(m)$ for $m>4$ is or is not prime.

Comment: Many thanks @DanielWainfleet for your attention and feedback. My idead is try to get equations, these were my attempts, involving the Euler's totient function and Dedekind psi function. Feel free to study if it is possible (I have more equations, but it seems that don't encode, in exclusive, primes of the form $n^n+1$). I can to provide these in comments.

Comment: (1/2) **All users:** You can to prove that the equations $$\varphi(A^{\psi(A)})=A^AB^B$$ and $$\psi(A^A)=A^{B^B}(A+1)$$ hold for positive integers $A$ and $B$ with $A=B^B+1$ a prime number ($A>1$). I've tried to check these equations with a Pari/GP program (my computational evidence is small is for a few integer segments).

Comment: (2/2) For the divisor-counting function $d(n)=\sigma_0(n)=\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}1$ and the sum of divisors function $\sigma(n)$ one can to prove other identities but these seem that don't encode the sequence, for instance $$d(\varphi(X))=d(Y)\cdot\varphi(d(X))$$ for $X=A^{A-1}$ and $Y=B^B$ with $A=B^B+1$ prime; another identity is $\sigma(A^Y)=\frac{A^A-1}{d(A^Y)-1}$, I wrote around  six more equations similar than those stated in the body of the post. If you're interested I can to add these in the comments.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet if $n$ is a power if $2$ then $n^n+1$ is not always Fermat. For instance, $8^8+1=16777217$ is divisible by the Fermat number $257$, which is impossible for any Fermat number besides $257$ itself. To get a Fermat number $n$ must be a power of $2$ whose exponent is also a power of $2$.

Answer (score 3):

Claims 1 and 2 are true. Let $n^n+1$ be a prime number. Then

$$
\begin{align}
\varphi(\varphi(n^n+1))&=\varphi(n^n)\\
&=n^{n-1}\varphi(n)\\
&=\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}n^n\\
&=\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}(n^n+2-2)\\
&=\frac{\varphi(n)}{n}(\psi(n^n+1)-2).
\end{align}
$$
which proves Claim 1. Let's call Claim 2a the statement
$$
\varphi(\varphi(n^n+1))^n=(n^n)^{n-1}\cdot\varphi(n)^n
$$
and call Claim 2b the statement:
$$
\psi(n^n)^n=\psi(n)^n\cdot(n^n)^{n-1}
$$
which are just the separate conjuncts of Claim 2 taking as you suggest $A=n^n+1$ and $B=n$. It's thus obvious that to prove Claim 2 it suffices to prove Claims 2a and 2b.

Proof of Claim 2a:
$$
\begin{align}
\varphi(\varphi(n^n+1))^n&=\varphi(n^n)^n\\
&=(n^{n-1}\varphi(n))^n\\
&=n^{n(n-1)}\varphi(n)^n\\
&=(n^n)^{n-1}\cdot\varphi(n)^n
\end{align}
$$

Proof of Claim 2b:
$$
\begin{align}
\psi(n^n)^n&=(n^{n-1}\psi(n))^n\\
&=\psi(n)^n\cdot(n^n)^{n-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your edit and this nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

How good are you at power towers?

Given that $n^n+1$ must be a multiple of $n^m+1$ when $m$ is a divisor of $n$ and $n/m$ is odd, we can easily see that $n$ must be a power of $2$, thus $n=2^k$.

But wait, there's more. Suppose we try small values of $k$. We nicely get primes when $k=0,1,2$, but for $k=3$ we discover that $8^8+1$ is divisible by $257=2^8+1$, as well as $97$ and $673$.

If $n=2^k$ and $k=pq$ for some odd $p$, then

$n^n+1=2^{pq\cdot n}+1,$

and we conclude that our intended prime is in fact divisible by $2^{q\cdot n}+1$, which forces the number to be composite unless $p$ is forced to $1$ or $k=pq=0$. (The case we tried, $n=8$, corresponds to $p=3,q=1$.) So not only do we need $n=2^k$ for a prime, we also need $k=0$ or $k=2^l$ meaning the next candidate after $n=4$ is not until $n=16$. More broadly the only acceptable values of $n$ are given by the rapidly growing sequence

$1,2,4,16,256,...,$

where each term after those shown is the square of the previous term. The $n=4$ term is just $257$, but the $n=16$ candidate would already have more than twenty decimal digits.

We can express candidate function values greater than $1^1+1=2$ as Fermat numbers, specifically $\Phi_{2^l+l}$ for nonnegative whole numbers $l$. In terms of this the candidates defined above may be rendered:

$2,\Phi_1,\Phi_3,\Phi_6,\Phi_{11},\Phi_{20},\Phi_{37},\Phi_{70},...$

The first three of these entries are prime and the next four [are known to be composite](http://www.prothsearch.com/fermat.html). So the next possible prime in this list is $\Phi_{70}$, corresponding to $n=2^{64}$. Although Pepin's Test offers a simplified means to assess primal-ity, the sheer size of this number prevents a computational solution in a reasonable time with current technology. A proof that all Fermat numbers above $\Phi_4$ are composite would solve the problem definitively.

Comment: Many thanks for this nice answer. I'm interested, in particular, in Lambert W function. I was interested in equations as $\varphi\left(x^{\sigma(x)}\sigma(x)^x\right)=2^{x-1} x^{3x-1}\varphi(x)$ involving odd perfect numbers (post with identifier **336501** of MathOverflow) but I have not idea of how to combine the definition/theory of Lambert W function with this kind of equations. I'm interested in this special function because this has a lot of applications as you know from the Wikipedia *Lambert W function*.